# Does Google Image Search save the searched image?

Tags: google-image-search

I am searching an image via Google image-search with the 'Drag & Drop' method.

My question is, if I drag an image from my computer into Google image-search, it will show the result (if any) but what happens to the dragged (uploaded) image?

Will it be removed/deleted or will it be stored in Google's servers or any another place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like they will keep a copy of the image.

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?p=searchbyimagepage&hl=en

> **How Google uses the image you search with**
>
> When you search by image, any images or URLs that you upload will be
>   stored by Google. Google uses those images and URLs solely to provide
>   and improve our products and services.

Comment: so it's not safe to image search ...Thanks Steve :)

Comment: sorry i could not vote because it shows error, required 15 reputatations.... so once again thanks

Comment: The question is about drag and drop image search, your answer is about URL search, the answer is wrong.